# Twitter API and RT information

Tags: api, search, twitter

With the twitter search API you can request "only original tweets" or "only retweets".

If you are requesting "everything", how can you determine for each result which one is a RT and which one is not ?  If this is a RT, how can I know who the original author is ?

Am I missing an option to make the API add some "retweet information" to status results ?

Answer (score 1):

Retweets should have `retweeted_status` and inside it the `user` object.